# SSRS font color change

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone help me to create a expression in SSRS report. I need to change the font color of an dynamic date value based on some conditions.I tried this expression

```
=iif( (Sum(Fields!Today_count.Value)) > 0,          
iif((((Sum(Fields!Today_count.Value) -
sum(Fields!Previousday_count.Value)) / 
sum(Fields!Previousday_count.Value))*100)>31,"Red",         
iif((((Sum(Fields!Today_count.Value)-sum(Fields!Previousday_count.Value)) /   
sum(Fields!Previousday_count.Value))*100)<-31,"Red","Black")),"Black")
```

. I need only values that satisfy this condition to be colored. But all the values font color are changing . Can anyone pls help on this .

Default color value is black , if the percentage of value is between -31 to 31 % the font color of CURRENT DATE value has to be changed to red.To be more clear one of the field in my report is "create_dt" where my query is like -> cast(convert(varchar,b.create_dt,112) as datetime) between @start_dt and @end_dt

Comment: Looks like you are setting font color to black if it is 0, and if the growth of the sum is not between -31 and 31 turn it red. What is your default color? Right before the ,"Black") you have an empty set of quotes, should that be Black as well?

Comment: As an aside, have a look at the `switch` function.  It saves you having to nest so many `iif` statements like you have.

Comment: @WyattShipman my default color value is black

Comment: @iamdave : im checking only 3 conditions , so felt comfortable with nested iif statement

Comment: @umajeyaraman  The `switch` function does exactly the same thing, is more readable, easier to extend and requires less typing.  It really is better in every possible way.